# How to designate a variable within a string quote in R?

Tags: r, string, variables, escaping, rscript

Hi Stack Overflow community, thank you so much in advance for any help on this issue.

I'm interested in writing a non-interactive Rscript that designates variables that are read in from the command line. For example:

```
Rscript ./script {1} {2}
```

The {1} is an argument I pass to the script and the {2} is an argument corresponding to the full path that points to a text file composed of one column, filled with numbers and names.

I wrote a small Rscript whose function is to read in the text file and delete the rows that contain a particular string. I want the string to correspond to a variable I designate at the beginning of the script and provide on the command line. So far, my script reads:

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

POP = args[1]
FREQ = args[2]

# read the file in 
POP.freq <- paste0("FREQ")

# write a function to remove the rows that hold the string "POP"

clean_names <- function(x, ...) { 
  POP.freq[!POP.freq$POP == "POP",]
}
```

The problem is that in the function where I designate the string to be removed: "POP", R reads this literally as "POP" and not whatever the argument is I am trying to pass it (usually the name of a country e.g. Germany). In bash, the $ designates the variable but I am not sure what the equivalent is in R. How can I designate that POP is a variable within the string but also let R know that it is a string I am trying to identify.

I would appreciate any advice on this matter!

Comment: Instead of `"POP"` can you stick with `args[1]` i.e. `POP.freq[!POP.freq$POP == args[1],]`?

Comment: Or you should use `POP` without quotes since it's a variable.

Comment: Both of these options fail to achieve the desired result unfortunately. R does not recognize either as being the designated variable. I wonder if it's because of the syntax coupled with the POP? (a $ in the first case and then a "" in the second)